# Ionic local notifications. Is there a way to disable permissions from code?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I’m just looking to disable the permissions to trigger notifications using the app and not the settings of the device.

Answer (score 0):

> disable the permissions to trigger notifications using the app and not the settings of the device.

No. It is a user controlled feature.